# Error in form display correction in draggable and droppable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a two draggable div.I wrote a javascript inside the drop function.When I drag the first draggable div and click the first drag div ,its call the second draggable onclick function.

```
$(function() {
  $(".draggable1").draggable({
    cursor: "crosshair"
  });


  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $("#close1").show();
      $('#first').on('click', function(event) {
        // alert("hi");
        $("#formnew1").show();
        event.preventDefault();
      });
      $('#close1').on('click', function(event) {
        // alert("hi");
        $("#formnew1").hide();
        location.reload();

        event.preventDefault();
      });

    }
  });
});
$(function() {
  $(".draggable2").draggable({
    cursor: "crosshair"
  });


  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $("#close2").show();
      $('#second').on('click', function(event) {
        // alert("hi");
        $("#formnew2").show();
        event.preventDefault();
      });
      $('#close2').on('click', function(event) {
        // alert("hi");
        $("#formnew2").hide();
        location.reload();

        event.preventDefault();
      });

    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7078p7kc/9/

Answer (score 0):

You call `$("#droppable").droppable` twice and so, only the last one applies. You should combine them like below:

```
$(function() {

  $(".draggable").draggable({
    cursor: "crosshair"
  });

  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {

      var droppedElement = ui.draggable;
      var formnew = droppedElement.find(".formnew");
      var closeButton = droppedElement.find('.close');

      droppedElement.on('click', function(event) {
        formnew.show();
        event.preventDefault();
      });

      closeButton.show();
      closeButton.on('click', function(event) {
        formnew.hide();
        location.reload();
        event.preventDefault();
      });

    }
  });
});
```

[**Online Demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/42cr7eua/20/)